# Is it correct to say "As I complete it" or "When I complete it"

Tags: conjunctions

The full sentence is "I will send the forms back one-by-one as I complete them".

Is it correct to use *as* here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either "when" or "as" can be used to say when the forms will be returned.

> I will send the forms back **when** I complete them.

sounds as if they will all be completed and sent back together.

> I will send the forms back **as** I complete them.

means the forms will be sent when they are completed, maybe in multiple groups.

> I will send the forms back **one-by-one** **as** I complete them.

Using **one-by-one** along with **as** makes it extra clear that the forms will be completed and sent back individually.

See  [Merriam-Webster "as"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as)
conjunction
5: while, when
*spilled the milk as she got up*